# Built-in ethernet card is not detected

Tags: 10.04, networking

I have Ubuntu 10.04 installed on a desktop computer with an MSI ms-7142 motherboard. Both when I was testing and after I installed, it can't find any network card. There is a built-in card, but lspci doesn't show any network card. I haven't yet tossed an external PCI card in to check and see if it can find that, but I was curious to know if there are any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Check that your ethernet card is enabled in bios,also post the result of `lspci | grep Ethernet`

Comment: If it's a PCI card please provide the output from: lspci -vv

Comment: @karthick, **facepalm** I always forget to check the simple things first. The card was disabled in bios, whoops!

Comment: Oke it's always a good thing to look at your bios first for these type of problems :) Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you check all of the possible settings:

1. Is the card enabled in your BIOS?
2. Is it present in `lspci -vv`?